# Does .NET use WSOCK32.DLL at all?

Tags: .net, sockets, intercept

My final aim is cumbersome a bit. I have to get notified about any web requests outbound from within my C# application, which contains some black-box components.

My initial guess is pretty simple: in the Windows environment `WSA` is used to send web requests. That means if i intercept `socket` function call, i will be notified about every single web request outbound.

My following steps are pretty straightforward. 
C++/CLI DLL which should make injection in `socket` function was created.

Well i'm new to this technique, but some success with this step was achieved. For a very beginning i created a simple function `injection_body` which ouptuts `"intercepted"` into console and does not return the control to the original `socket`. That means any attempt to create a new socket will show `"intercepted"` line and throw an exception, probably due to the stack corruption. Well i'm ok with that for a while.

`socket` function before the injection:

```
7635430A 8B FF                mov         edi,edi  
7635430C 55                   push        ebp  
7635430D 8B EC                mov         ebp,esp  
7635430F A1 50 A0 38 76       mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[7638A050h]  
76354314 83 EC 0C             sub         esp,0Ch  
76354317 3D 73 2D 35 76       cmp         eax,76352D73h
...
```

and after

```
7635430A E9 61 D4 DB F8       jmp         injection_body (6F111770h)  
7635430F A1 50 A0 38 76       mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[7638A050h]  
76354314 83 EC 0C             sub         esp,0Ch  
76354317 3D 73 2D 35 76       cmp         eax,76352D73h  
...
```

If `socket` called from native code of C++/CLI DLL directly, the injection works as intended: application shows `"intercepted"` and crushes. It proves injection to be made properly.

But this code

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(
       HttpWebRequest.Create("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask")
       .GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
      )
      Console.WriteLine(new string(reader.ReadToEnd().Take(100).ToArray()));
```

works normally, i. e. it prints a piece of the page instead of `"intercepted"` and does not cause any exception.

But if the same approach is applied to `CreateFileW` WinAPI finction it will affect both parts (either managed and native) of the application.

**Finally my main question is:** why i cannot intercept `HttpWebRequest`? Where i'm going wrong?

Now i can see several 'possible' reasons for that behavior, but all of them don't look to be valid. Can `HttpWebRequest` use something else than `WSOCK32.DLL`? Can it use WSA lilrary instance, loaded not into my adress space?
Could MS cast some evil spells on `HttpWebRequest`?

I have no idea how to figure out what's the real reason for that behavior and how to fix it.

Comment: .NET likely uses ws2_32.dll for socket functions, and probably `WSASocket()` over `socket()`. `HttpWebRequest` might not implement HTTP directly -- [WinHTTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384273.aspx) is a possibility.

Comment: It might even be using stuff like `http.sys` for some parts. Why not just use something like Wireshark to monitor the communication instead?

Comment: @Luaan Thank you for a reply, but Wireshark seems to be a standalone application, while i need to handle requests programmatically.

Comment: A great tool I have used in the past to figure out what API calls a program is actually making is a freeware tool called [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) (Don't be afraid of the Alpha tag, the program is stable, it is just the author wants to add more features before it is "released"). Another one that is good for when you have no idea if a dll is being referenced or not (like your situation) is [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). It will show you all Dlls that where loaded in to memory while your program ran.

Comment: You *need* to do this programmatically? Why? Are you trying to prevent some 3rd party component you're using from authenticating with its home server or what? :P Note that the communication is using the asynchronous API, so you need to inject into those.

Comment: @Lunaan No, i'm not trying to block authentication by intercepting WSA because i easily do this with any firewall ;) Actually i want to collect some staticsics. Thanks for pointing to async api.

Comment: Can't you just use an HTTP proxy (FiddlerCore?) through which all traffic flows?

Comment: @CodeCaster How i'm supposed to redirect requests, generated by third-party library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for you comments!

Intercepting `WSASocket` from `ws2_32.dll` allows to detect `HttpWebRequest` calls, but still cannot be accepted as a solution.

In case of black-box-like components a lot of different APIs to intercept come up.

> wininet.dll realization does not depend on the winsock.dll ws2_32.dll, but independent existence...
>
> WinHTTP.dll do not depend on the winsock or ws2_32, also operate independently.

Well, this API seems to be a nice wheel to reinvent again and again...

Intercepting everything does not seem to be the proper way. Investigation with tools like Scott Chamberlain suggests is probably the best solution.